# Is it possible to set priority for item in java.util.PriorityQueue?

Tags: java, priority-queue

Assume I have a bunch of jobs in `PriorityQueue`, is there a build-in method, other than iterate items explicitly,  that can have access to some item and change it priority? I've checked the [API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) and it just supports operations in a heap.

I was wondering if it's possible write my own priority queue that can maintain the heap property (delete min in `O(1)` and insert in `O(log(n))`) as well as provide reference to each item in `O(1)`. It's like a combination of hash table and heap. I've no idea about how to implement it.

Update: many references say processes scheduling is one of applications of priority queue. How does OS modify priority efficiently when we use `nice`?

Comment: You can remove the element, change its priority and re-add it, which is probably how you'd implement priority change anyway. Note that it isn't a good idea to have mutable objects in a sorted collection, unless you can guarantee that no-one else plays around with priorities.

Comment: @biziclop yeah, this can be done in `O(1)` only if changing the current highest priority. What if I'd like to change other jobs in the priority queue? Do I have to iterate to look up it?

Comment: No, because your heap is sorted. `O(logn)` to look it up and remove it (using `remove()`) and `O(logn)` to reinsert it is `O(logn)` overall.

Comment: No, sorry, you're right, `remove()` is a linear time operation.

Comment: By the way, readjusting priorities of already enqueued items is indeed slow but that's generally not a problem, as it's something that happens very infrequently compared to the two main operations. In an OS what might easily happen is that you adjust the `nice` but it won't change anything in the queue. Only when the thread reaches the front of the queue, is removed and requeued, does `nice` take effect.

Comment: @biziclop So, do you mean `nice` won't take effect immediately even if  under preemptive scheduling?

Comment: It depends on the scheduler but it's a perfectly sensible thing to do in a scheduler that uses run queues. In real life most OSes either use multilevel queueing or do away with run queues altogether. `nice` is handy because it's an abstract way of telling the scheduler how important a task is, but how that information is interpreted varies.

Comment: @biziclop good explaination! Thanks.